# Migrate WindowsAzure.ServiceBus to Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

Microsoft will deprecated support of Classic API for Service Bus at November 2021 (as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/deprecate-service-bus-management))

In our code we use [WindowsAzure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/) package.
It is an ol package and Microsoft suggets to use new [Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/) package.

`WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` package contain [GetQueues(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.namespacemanager.getqueues?view=azure-dotnet) method. This method can use `filter` parameter for filtration queues by name or properties. It is very useful if a `ServiceBus` has many Queues.

But I can't find equivalent of this feature in new `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` package.

How can I implement filter feature in new package?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I implement filter feature in new package?

You will need to use [`GetQueuesAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.servicebusadministrationclient.getqueuesasync?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Messaging_ServiceBus_Administration_ServiceBusAdministrationClient_GetQueuesAsync_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) method in [`ServiceBusAdministrationClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.servicebusadministrationclient?view=azure-dotnet) class to get this information.

```
Please see the sample code:

using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Administration;

namespace SO67703647
{
    class Program
    {
        static string connectionString = "your-connection-string";
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var adminClient = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(connectionString);
            var queuesListingResult = adminClient.GetQueuesAsync();
            await foreach (var item in queuesListingResult)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("=======================");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to terminate the application.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Method `GetQueuesAsync` do not support filter feature unfortunately.

Comment: Thats' correct. You will need to do filtering on the client side only.

Comment: Understood. It is a bad news for us, because old library used OData filter. And we can set up filter for retrieving only small portion of queues.

Comment: Azure SDK team had an [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/11817) where they tried to capture the needed APIs. Unfortunately, not everything was captured. I would advise you to raise a separate issue and link to the original one. The library has been GA-ed, so I doubt the original issue will be looked at much.

Comment: "var queuesListingResult = adminClient.GetQueuesAsync();"  Note there is no "await" (after the "=") like you normally see.    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.administration.servicebusadministrationclient.getqueuesasync?view=azure-dotnet    "Azure.AsyncPageable" .. Go figure.

Comment: Bumping into the same issues. Unfortunately, I found that the paged access to the full list of e.g. Queues, when there is a considerable amount of queues in the namespace, is not consistent in the returned list, i.e. the number of pages / total queue count via the paging mechanism is inconsistent, and therefore so are the filter results. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/40773